# RDLC ReportViewer toobox cannot be used in VS 2022

Tags: report, visual-studio-2022, rdlc, reportviewer

I am trying to get the report items in vb.net in visual studio 2022.

I have installed the RDLC extension for the 2022 version from Microsoft and able to see the Report and Report Wizard when I go to Project > Add New Item within my project.

However when I am in a regular Windows Form, I don't have the Report Viewer in my toolbox.

I have right-clicked on the toolbox and selected "Choose Items..." from the context menu. In the "Choose Toolbox Items" dialog box, click the ".NET Framework Components" tab I selected 'ReportViewer' and OK. But the toolbox still does not appear, it only appears if 'Show All' is clicked, even then it cannot be used ([the 'ReportViewer' view in my VS that I can't use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjDdy.png)[the 'ReportViewer' view in my VS that I can't use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHdvC.png)).

I want the 'ReportViewer' toobox can be used in my project in VS 2022. I've tried everything on the internet but I haven't found a solution to this problem yet.

Thank you in advance for any help!